# How to embed a form from a DLL into an Inno Setup wizard page?

Tags: delphi, dll, embed, inno-setup

I've built some VCL forms in Delphi DLL's which show during the Inno Setup installation. However, it would be much more concise if I could embed these forms into the Inno Setup wizard.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way for you will be to create an exported function which will do all the stuff in your library. The necessary minimum for such function is a parameter for the handle of the Inno Setup control into which your form should be embedded. The next necessary thing you need to know for embedding are bounds, but those you can get with the Windows API function call on the library side.

Here is the Delphi part showing the unit with the form from your DLL project:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids;

type
  TEmbeddedForm = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  end;

procedure CreateEmbeddedForm(ParentWnd: HWND); stdcall;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TEmbeddedForm }

procedure TEmbeddedForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

{ CreateEmbeddedForm }

procedure CreateEmbeddedForm(ParentWnd: HWND); stdcall;
var
  R: TRect;
  Form: TEmbeddedForm;
begin
  Form := TEmbeddedForm.Create(nil);
  Form.ParentWindow := ParentWnd;
  Form.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  GetWindowRect(ParentWnd, R);
  Form.BoundsRect := R;
  Form.Show;
end;

exports
  CreateEmbeddedForm;

end.
```

And here is the Inno Setup script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "MyDLL.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure CreateEmbeddedForm(ParentWnd: HWND);
  external 'CreateEmbeddedForm@files:MyDLL.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
  CreateEmbeddedForm(CustomPage.Surface.Handle);
end;
```

---

Just to note, Inno Setup supports also [`COM Automation`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptautomation.htm), so the above way is not the only option how to embed an object into the wizard form. However, it's the simplest one.

Oh, and yet one note, which might be good for you to know. If you'd ever need to execute a certain Inno Setup script code from your library, you could do it by making a callback function on the Inno Setup side and passing and executing it on the DLL side.

Comment: P.S. I'm intentionally ignoring the result of the `GetWindowRect` function call (but you shouldn't), because where would you inplace the form if that call fails anyway. Raising an exception from your DLL is useless because you won't get its object to Inno Setup. Though you can fix this weakness if you add a parameter for bounds to the exported function, or you can e.g. use the existing `SetLastError` mechanism with the 29th bit (with calling `DllGetLastError` in IS) at least for reporting to the IS side that finding of the parent bounds has failed. That's what I'm leaving to you to decide.

Comment: P.P.S. I would strongly prefer to use the first option since adding bounds parameter to the function gives you even better flexibility.

Comment: How do you pass a function from IS to dll?

Comment: @Sertac, e.g. [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/1mDe32JY). It's quite tricky from a usual implementation point of view, because every procedure defined in Inno Setup is actually a method of a hidden object. It took me some time to realize this when I was attempting to make callbacks. Then I remembered that all the event methods in a script (even those you define by yourself) are objectless procedures, and so there must be a hidden object wrapping them all to methods.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. I'll be sure to ask a proper question if I ever need it. :)

Comment: Thank you, it's awesome to know that Stack Overflow has an expert in Inno Setup :-)

Comment: Strangely, when I try out adding VCL styles to my installer, the DLL forms pick up some of the skinning, but not all. Will ask new question about this.