# Showing Delphi Form inside a Inno Setup wizard

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, pascal

I have a Delphi form in a DLL and I want To show it inside a Wizard page in Inno setup.  I am following an example from this question:

[How to embed a form from a DLL into an Inno Setup wizard page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795300/how-to-embed-a-form-from-a-dll-into-an-inno-setup-wizard-page)

I use these lines of code to export my Delphi form:

```
procedure CreateWizardForm(ParentWnd: HWND);stdcall;
var
  R: TRect;
  Form: TOpenSQLServerForm;// the from i want to show
begin
  Form := TOpenSQLServerForm.Create(nil);
  Form.ParentWindow := ParentWnd;
  Form.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  GetWindowRect(ParentWnd, R);
  Form.BoundsRect := R;
  Form.Show;
end;
```

And in the Library I have:

```
library LoadServerName;

uses
  Winapi.Windows,System.SysUtils, System.Classes, VCL.Forms,VCl.dialogs,
  OpenSQLServer in 'OpenSQLServer.pas' {OpenSQLServerForm};

{$R *.res}

exports
  CreateWizardForm;

begin
end.
```

And finally, I use my DLL in Inno Setup in this way:

```
procedure CreateWizardForm(ParentWnd:HWND);stdcall;
external 'CreateWizardForm@files:LoadServerName.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 'Caption', 'Description');
  CreateWizardForm(CustomPage.surface.Handle);
end;
```

When I run Inno Setup, I expect to see my wizard form inside the CustomPage, but it didn't show my form at all. What's the problem?

Comment: Were there errors?  Is there anything more to your ISS file?  Did you use LoadDLL to load the Delphi DLL? You might want to debug the DLL to see if it's getting an exception or other error.  Logging in the DLL might help too.

Comment: @martheil there is no error I expect to see my Delphi form inside the customPage when run my installer  but it didnt show my delphi form

Comment: Your `CreateWizardForm()` function is using Delphi's default `register` calling convention.  Did you specify that when you declared the function in Inno?  Inno assumes `stdcall` by default. Make sure you don't have a mismatch.

Comment: On a side note, `Form:= TOpenSQLServerForm.Create(nil); Form.ParentWindow := ParentWnd;` can be simplified to `Form := TOpenSQLServerForm.CreateParented(ParentWnd);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I Edit my Question and i think use correct way to call dll function

Comment: "*i think use correct way to call dll function*" - actually no, because you DO have a calling convention mismatch. The `register` convention is NOT the same as the `stdcall` convention, especially when passing parameter values. So you likely end up assigning an invalid `HWND` to the DLL's `TForm`. You need to either 1) change the declaration of the function in the DLL to `procedure CreateWizardForm(ParentWnd: HWND); stdcall;`, or 2) change the declaration of the function in Inno to `procedure CreateWizardForm(ParentWnd:HWND);
external 'CreateWizardForm@files:LoadServerName.dll register';`

Comment: @RemyLebeau shame on me oh i forgat this. i will try it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220574/discussion-between-sina-and-remy-lebeau).